# Software Center not working in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, software-center

I am having trouble with the Software Center in Ubuntu 12.04.

When I write Software-center in Terminal, this says :

```
** (software-center:3203): WARNING **: Failed to load shared library 'libwebkitgtk-3.0.so.0' referenced by the typelib: libwebkitgtk-3.0.soso: no se puede abrir el archivo del objeto compartido: No existe el archivo o el directorio
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 131, in <module>
    session = webkit.get_default_session()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/types.py", line 43, in function
    return info.invoke(*args, **kwargs)
gi._glib.GError: Could not locate webkit_get_default_session: `webkit_get_default_session': /usr/lib/libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0.so.0: undefined symbol: webkit_get_default_session
```

How to solve this?

Please Help.

Comment: Open the terminal and try this `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libwebkitgtk-3.0-0`. Then again try launching `Software center`.

Answer (score 3):

Open your terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and type as

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center
```

Then try to re launch it.

Comment: Software catalog update was successful.
I write software-center

Comment: And I see ** (software-center:4211): WARNING **: Failed to load shared library 'libwebkitgtk-3.0.so.0' referenced by the typelib: libwebkitgtk-3.0.soso: no se puede abrir el archivo del objeto compartido: **

Comment: **No existe el archivo o el directorio
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 131, in <module>
    session = webkit.get_default_session()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/types.py", line 43, in function
    return info.invoke(*args, **

Comment: how to solve this please help me

Answer (score 0):

Click on the link and go to step 9.

You can avoid the command "**dist-upgrade**"

This method worked for me.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PackageManagerTroubleshootingProcedure

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer to provide the solution here, not only mentioning links. Please, take a time and add the more important steps *here*. Thanks!